# Code not working with Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer-9, textarea

For whatever reason I cannot get the following code to work at all in IE9 but it works in Firefox, Chrome, and Opera:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Laughing Man Productions²-Administrator Portal</title>

<!--[if !IE 9]> <!--><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.lmpgames.com/WEB401/W2/css/login_page.css"/><!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.lmpgames.com/WEB401/W2/css/login_page_IE.css"/>
<![endif]-->


</head>

<body>
<div class="login_bg">
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset class="fset">
      <div class="username_text">
        Username/Email Address:
          <span class="username_field">
            <input name="txtbUName" type="text" style="background-color:#DDDDDD;" value="Username" size="20" maxlength="60" />
          </span>
      </div><br/>

      <div class="password_text">
        Password:
          <span class="password_field">
            <input name="txtbPWord" type="password" style="background-color:#DDDDDD;" value="Password" size="20" maxlength="16" />
          </span>
      </div><br/>

      <div class="sub">
        <input name="btnSubmit" type="button" onclick="formatUName(this.form)" value="Submit" />
      </div>

      <textarea name="txtaFOutput" class="txta" cols="1" rows="1">

      </textarea>  
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  </div>



<script type="application/javascript">
    function formatUName(form)
    {
        //Set up variables and references for use later on
        var button = form.btnSubmit;
        var txta = form.txtaFOutput;
        var username = form.txtbUName;
        var password = form.txtbPWord;
        var uName = "default";
        var pWord = "";

        uName = username.value; //Obtain the value of the username field on submit

        //Then remove spaces from the value and change all letters to uppercase
        uName = uName.replace(/\s+/g, '');      
        uName = uName.toUpperCase();

        //Finally print the formatted username to the textarea
        txta.value = uName + " is your username";       
    }
</script>  


</body>     
</html>
```

When I load the page up in IE and click on submit nothing happens.  I have tried changing the .value to innerHTML and innerText but neither of them worked in IE either.

Edit:

After fiddling around with IE I finally managed to get the debugging running and it spat out this error:

> Line: 23
>   Error: Unable to get value of the property 'appendChild': object is null or undefined

Edit 2:

Disregard the previous error.  IE was allowing Vuze to inject Javascript code through a plugin that I did not know Vuze had installed.  Disabled them and now the new error message is about my function name:

> Line 35:
>   The value of the property 'formatUName' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Comment: Your comment syntax is definitively wrong. Use `//` for line comments

Comment: Do you get any errors in IE? Have you tried debugging it, until what parts does it work?

Comment: @Bergi Changed the comment tags to backslashes no change.  As for debugging I cannot.  According to IE's dev tool my function has no executable code and thus breakpoints within the script tags are invalid.

Comment: You should be using *forward* slashes, not *back* slashes. Also, only on the JS. Leave the HTML comments as they are.

Comment: @DannyBeckett Sorry they are forward slashes.  I get them mixed up from time to time.

Comment: Thanks for the error message. It seems you didn't post the whole code though, because you don't use `appendChild` anywhere here. Looks like the mistake is somewhere else. Does it say line 23 of what file?

Comment: @Bergi Actually no, that error was because IE was allowing Vuze to inject it's code into my pages.  I disabled the Vuze plugin and now it spits out that formatUName is not defined.

Comment: @Geowil: You might still have a syntax error (on the comment `Obtain…`). Then try removing the script type attribute. Then try to prefix the function call with `window.`

Comment: @Bergi I fixed it.  It was a combo of the Vuze plugin, the suggestion that Nathaniel had me try (changing from button to submit), and a random IE tantrum about running completely valid code.  See my answer for full details.

Answer (score 1):

When I run this in IE, the JavaScript works fine, but the form does not submit. If that is the problem you are facing, the cause is:

```
<input name="btnSubmit" type="button" onclick="formatUName(this.form)" value="Submit" />
```

Change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`. Browser behavior is unpredictable when you have a `type="button"` in a form that lacks an explicit submit button.

Comment: After changing type to submit the code still does not work for me.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what is and isn't happening? Does the javascript get executed? Does the form submit? Try adding `alert("foo");` into the javascript function to see whether it is executed.

Comment: When I click on the submit button nothing happens. Cannot place breaks because IE does not see executable code in my script tags. See my original question for the error message I was able to get IE to spit out at me.

Comment: what happens when you add `alert("foo!");` into the top of the formatUName function? Does the alert pop-up when you press submit?

Comment: No but I am getting a new error now that states that the function name formatUName is not defined.

Comment: can you update your original post to show the current state of the code (with the changes to the commenting, type=status, and the new javascript alert)? It's possible that in the process of making the changes, you had a typo or something pop-up. I should add that I'm still having no trouble executing this code in IE9 (or IE10 for that matter).

Comment: The problem was setting type from button to submit.  This cause the code to not execute properly.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, `<!-- comment -->` is the correct syntax for a comment.

Javascript, on the other hand, uses ANSI C-standard comments, `// comment` and `/* comment */`.

You need to change:

```
function formatUName(form)
{
    <!-->Set up variables and references for use later on
    var button = form.btnSubmit;
    var txta = form.txtaFOutput;
    var username = form.txtbUName;
    var password = form.txtbPWord;
    var uName = "default";
    var pWord = "";

    uName = username.value; <!--> Obtain the value of the username field on submit

    <!--> Then remove spaces from the value and change all letters to uppercase
    uName = uName.replace(/\s+/g, '');      
    uName = uName.toUpperCase();

    <!--> Finally print the formatted username to the textarea
    txta.value = uName + " is your username";
}
```

To:

```
function formatUName(form)
{
    // Set up variables and references for use later on
    var button = form.btnSubmit;
    var txta = form.txtaFOutput;
    var username = form.txtbUName;
    var password = form.txtbPWord;
    var uName = "default";
    var pWord = "";

    uName = username.value; // Obtain the value of the username field on submit

    // Then remove spaces from the value and change all letters to uppercase
    uName = uName.replace(/\s+/g, '');      
    uName = uName.toUpperCase();

    // Finally print the formatted username to the textarea
    txta.value = uName + " is your username";
}
```

Comment: You're correct that Geowil should correct his comment syntax, but IE does not seem to be choking on that when I run his code.

Comment: As mentioned above, changing the comment tags did nothing to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple answers had pieces of the puzzle.  At first the error I was getting was due to a Vuze plugin that IE was allowing to inject Conduit Javascript into all of my webpages.  The second error was Internet Explorer being itself and bugging out for no reason.

After restarting IE after it stopped responding while testing the code started working, almost.  There was still a problem and it was caused by Nathaniel's suggestion of changing btnSubmit from a type of button to a type of submit.  This caused the code in all of my browsers to stop working; the text area would not properly update its value.

After changing the type back to button the code works in all tested browsers: IE9/Firefox 18.1/Opera 12.15/Chrome 28.

Comment: @Bergi Actually it is 12.  12.15.  Could have sworn it was 9 though.  I must have updated it and forgotten.